# replace integers in array Python

Tags: python, numpy

They told me to post a new question to the [second part of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917975/accessing-elements-in-array-python).

Is there some way I can replace the first 8 integers in the multidimensional array with 8 integers of array that I created for example:

```
    import Image
    import numpy as np

    im = Image.open("C:\Users\Jones\Pictures\1.jpg")
    pix = im.load() 
array=[0, 3, 38, 13, 7, 18, 3, 715]
    r, g, b = np.array(im).T
    print r[0:8]
```

Comment: I've tried to make a entire new array and add them to it the elements in array and the elements after the first 8 from multidimensional array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this:

```
r[0, :8] = array
```

It looks like you can use reading the [numpy docs on indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Comment: wow it was that simple I cant believe I was over thinking it by that much thank you so much I'm in debted to you